# Chrome extension Content Script not working on gmail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have been facing some serious issues here, i tried building a chrome extension for gmail, but neither my interface or the content script is not loading at all, I get to see this error whenever I inspect the popup console.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: 
This page cannot be scripted due to an ExtensionsSettings policy.
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://hchilaodbnedmljenkfdfpjmgmlkmpci/js/popup.js:247:17)
```

[image]

Is the error related to my JSON file ?

I declared the content script as follow

```html
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "description",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "*://mail.google.com/*",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "contentSettings"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/send.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/imagege1.png",
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/image1.png",
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
    "js/popper.min.js",
    "js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "*://mail.google.co.in/*",
    ],
    "css": [
      "css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "js": [
      "js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
      "js/bootstrap.js",
      "js/send.js",
      "js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

piece of  JS code is here in case anyone needs it

[image]

Comment: Formatted the snippet, removed the `<pre></pre>` around it.

Comment: Your question should show the relevant code that invokes executeScript.

Comment: The same code works on so many other website why not this one? The piece of code is very standard... My point is the content script as it is know is not executed on Gmail at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced was not even related to the content script, Im was within an organisation which network did not allow my extensions to be executed In the private gmail that we use, and that required a different token provided by the organisation itself which need to be used a a key in the manifest file.

Comment: I have the same problem but your explanation wasn't enough for me.could you explain more How can I get the token and How to use it in the manifest.json?

Comment: are you able to execute the extension inside your personnal gmail account?